# installing node on jenkins 2.0 using the pipeline plugin

Tags: node.js, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I am running the following docker image `jenkinsci/jenkins:2.0-rc-1` to try out jenkins 2.0, and the "pipeline" view.

I can't seem to install node. Here's my pipeline script:

```
node {
    //tool([name: 'node-5.10.1', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'])
    sh 'echo $(whoami)'
    sh 'node -v'
}
```

The response when this runs is:

```
[ci] Running shell script
+ whoami
+ echo jenkins
jenkins
[Pipeline] sh
[ci] Running shell script
+ node -v
/../durable-3b0b1b07/script.sh: 2: /../durable-3b0b1b07/script.sh: node: not found
```

Here's what i've tried:

- the jenkins NodeJS tool (which works correctly when used with a freestyle job)
- logging into the docker container and installing node manually, for the same user:

[image]

UPDATE:

Building on Jesse Glick's answer below, i added the result to my scripts `PATH`:

```
node { 
    def nodeHome = tool name: 'node-5.10.1', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
    env.PATH = "${nodeHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    sh 'npm install'
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Either

```
node {
  withEnv(["PATH+NODE=${tool name: 'node-5.10.1', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'}/bin"]) {
    sh 'node -v'
  }
}
```

or

```
node {
  def nodeHome = tool name: 'node-5.10.1', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
  sh "${nodeHome}/bin/node -v"
}
```

should work. See [JENKINS-28718](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28718) for further proposals.

By the way you can omit the `type` parameter and just use

```
tool 'node-5.10.1'
```

for brevity.

Comment: thanks! strange that it started working as soon as it was declared? i took it a step further by adding it to the local path so i could just run "node" later on in the script - i'll update my question now

Comment: Great answer, but follow-up question... How might I include the globally installed npm packages in the path as well?

Answer (score 7):

For me work next code:

```
node(){
  def nodeHome = tool 'nodejs5'
  env.PATH="${env.PATH}:${nodeHome}/bin"
  ...
  sh 'npm install'
}
```

nodejs5 is the name of the tool specified in Jenkins configuration.

Comment: You do not want to clobber other entries in `$PATH`.

Comment: yep, sorry remove to much from my code, have to be: `env.PATH="${env.PATH}:${nodeHome}/bin"` will update answer

Answer (score 1):

If anyone happens to deal with this issue on **Jenkins running on Windows**. Do the following:

```
def nodeHome = tool 'Node.js 6.9.5'
bat "\"${nodeHome}\"\\node.exe -v"
bat "\"${nodeHome}\"\\npm -v"
```