# jenkins pipeline nodeJs

Tags: node.js, jenkins-pipeline

My JenkinsFile script started throwing npm not found error. (it is working for maven but failing at npm)

```
    pipeline {
    environment {
    JENKINS='true'
     }
       agent any 
       stages{
    stage('change permissions') {
    steps {
        sh "chmod 777 ./mvnw "
    }
}

    stage('clean') {
    steps {
        sh './mvnw clean install'
    }
    }


    stage('yarn install') {
    steps{
        sh 'npm install -g yarn'
        sh 'yarn install'
    }
    }
    stage('yarn webpack:build') {
    steps {
        sh 'yarn webpack:build'
    }
    }

    stage('backend tests') {
    steps {
        sh './mvnw test'
    }
    }

    stage('frontend tests') {
    steps {
        sh 'yarn test'
    }
    }

    }
}
```

To fix that 
I am trying to setup NodeJs on my jenkins node. I installed the nodejs plugin and wrote the script

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node 6.x', configId: '<config-file-provider-id>') {
                sh 'npm config ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

as shown in the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin
I also setup nodejs on global tools config

I also tried the solution in the [installing node on jenkins 2.0 using the pipeline plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575480/installing-node-on-jenkins-2-0-using-the-pipeline-plugin?rq=1)

and it throws 
Expected to find ‘someKey "someValue"’ @ line 4, column 7.
    node {
error. 
but I am still getting npm not found error on jenkins. I am new to jenkins so any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

I was able to fix the issues. Followed the following link and was able to fix the issue. https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-starting-with-pipeline-doing-a-node-js-test-72c6057b67d4

Comment: This is really hard to answer without knowing more about your project setup. You should provide more information or go problem solving on Google.

Comment: I have edited the post with more information please let me know if it helps you understand more about my problem

Comment: You mentioned you were able to fix the issue - I think you should post that link with a brief explanation as an answer for the next fellow to come along and find this question. Glad you got it working tho!

Comment: @saiharshini - Did you get `yarn` commands working? If so, how?

Comment: @kwhitejr https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-starting-with-pipeline-doing-a-node-js-test-72c6057b67d4 I followed the instructions from this site. In my file I was missing "tools {nodejs “node”}" once I added that it worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Its a puzzle. ;)

Has a little *reference* trick.

You need to configure your jenkins to see your nodejs config name.

At Global Tool Configuration, you need define your node config name. It has reference to your Jenkinsfile reference.

[image: Image from Gustavo Apolinario post at Medium]

Look an Jenkingsfile adapted example with reference:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "node"}

  stages {    
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/xxxx'
      }
    }        
    stage('Install dependencies') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm i -save express'
      }
    }     
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
         sh 'node server.js'
      }
    }             
  }
}
```

Complete case to study: [Post at Medium by Gustavo Apolinario](https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-starting-with-pipeline-doing-a-node-js-test-72c6057b67d4)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you need different version of Node.js and npm, you can install NodeJS plugin for Jenkins.
Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Global tools configuration` and find `NodeJS` section.
Select the version you need and name it as you prefer. You can also add npm packages that needs to be installed globally.

In a declarative pipeline, just reference the correct version of node.js to use:

```
stage('Review node and npm installations') {
  steps {
    nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'node13') {
      sh 'npm -v'  //substitute with your code
      sh 'node -v'
    }
  }
}
```

Full example here: https://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2020/05/how-to-use-different-nodejs-versions-on.html

Comment: Thanks! Would you update `Global tools configuration` to `Global Tool Configuration`?